# 'Member' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: django, django-forms

My models are defined as:

```
class MembershipHistory(models.Model):
    mem_name = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mem_number')
    project_number = models.IntegerField()
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    evaluator_remark = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And this is my other model from which I make the `ForeignKey`

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    membership_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I defined my form as

```
class MembershipHistoryForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MembershipHistoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['mem_name'].queryset = Member.objects.get(user=self.user)
   #mem_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label="NAME")

    class Meta:
        model = MembershipHistory
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'project_number':forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Project Number'}),
            'project_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Project Name'}),
            'evaluator_remark':forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Evaluator Remark'}),
        }
```

Now, whenever I instantiate the form, I am not getting the following error

```
Django Version: 1.10.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'Member' object has no attribute 'all'
```

any ideas as to where is the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you check proper django docs [section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get), you can see that

```
get()

get(**kwargs)

Returns the object matching the given lookup parameters
```

which means it returns an object in proper case not queryset, but `form` needs queryset so instead of using `get` method use `filter`.

```
self.fields['mem_name'].queryset = Member.objects.filter(user=self.user)
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume its because you're not assigning a queryset to the `mem_name` queryset.

Use `filter` instead of `get`

```
Member.objects.filter(user=self.user)
```

Although at this point, I wonder why you need a queryset at all, it would make more sense to exclude this field from the form, then set the user before saving the instance.